# separate and outfile numeric values based on similarity of the values.

Tags: perl

I think perl can do this, but I am pretty new to perl.
Hoping somebody can help me. 
I have file like this (actual file is more than ten thousands lines, values are in ascending order, some values are duplicated).

---

1

2

2

35

45

---

I want to separate those lines into separate files based on the similarity of the values (for example difference of the value is less than 30).

outfile1

---

1

2

2

---

outfile2

---

35

45

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done very simply by just opening a new file every time it is necessary, i.e. for the first line of data and thereafter every time there is a gap of 30 or more.

This program expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($last, $fileno, $fh);

while (<>) {
  my ($this) = /(\d+)/;
  unless (defined $last and $this < $last + 30) {
    open $fh, '>', 'outfile'.++$fileno;
  }
  print $fh $_;
  $last = $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should really be easy. Just remember the previous value in a variable so you can see whether the difference is large enough. You also have to count the output files created so far so you can name a new file when needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $threshold = 30;

my $previous;
my $count_out = 0;
my $OUTPUT;
while (<>) {
    if (not defined $previous or $_ > $previous + $threshold) {
        open $OUTPUT, '>', "outfile" . $count_out++ or die $!;
    }
    print $OUTPUT $_;
    $previous = $_;
}
```